# Spring JMS Oracle AQ Too many transactions

Tags: spring, oracle10g, jms, oracle-aq

I have created a basic Spring applicatin to read from Oracle AQ. I am experiencing following issues. Kindly help me on this

1)- Messages placed on the queue (by PL/SQL code) prior to starting of my spring application are not dequeued by it.
2)- A message that is successfull read from the queue should be removed from the queue. This is not happening. All messages remain in Queue Table.
3)- Once a message is read, the process goes in block/waiting state, as shown by the log below, if any message is place on queue during that period, that message is ignored. It is taking 30 - 40 secs to commit the transaction

```
2012-02-08 13:26:37,700 DEBUG [org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer] - <Received message of type [class oracle.jms.AQjmsAdtMessage] from consumer [oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer@1989b5] of transactional session [oracle.jms.AQjmsSession@189c036]>
2012-02-08 13:26:37,700 DEBUG [org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.BeanPropertyStructMapper] - <Mapping column 'id' to property 'id' of type class java.math.BigDecimal>
2012-02-08 13:26:37,700 DEBUG [org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.BeanPropertyStructMapper] - <Mapping column 'type_cd' to property 'type_cd' of type class java.lang.String>
2012-02-08 13:26:37,700 INFO [com.test.oracle.aq.ProductDelegate] - <Product [id=6, type_cd=Test Product Code]>
2012-02-08 13:26:37,715 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - <Executing SQL update [INSERT INTO Product(id, type_cd) values(6, 'Test Product Code')]>
2012-02-08 13:26:37,731 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - <SQL update affected 1 rows>
2012-02-08 13:26:57,295 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction commit>
2012-02-08 13:26:57,295 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1860038]>
2012-02-08 13:26:57,295 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1860038] after transaction>
2012-02-08 13:26:57,295 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - <Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource>
```

4)- Why it is making soo many tansactions? While waiting on queue

```
2012-02-08 13:22:58,937 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer#0]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT>
2012-02-08 13:22:59,000 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Acquired Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@9b688e] for JDBC transaction>
2012-02-08 13:22:59,000 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Switching JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@9b688e] to manual commit>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,045 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction commit>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,045 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@9b688e]>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,061 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@9b688e] after transaction>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,061 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - <Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,061 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer#0]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,093 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Acquired Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@eca36e] for JDBC transaction>
2012-02-08 13:23:00,093 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Switching JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@eca36e] to manual commit>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,154 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction commit>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,154 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@eca36e]>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,155 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@eca36e] after transaction>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,155 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - <Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,155 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer#0]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,202 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Acquired Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@19b4748] for JDBC transaction>
2012-02-08 13:23:01,202 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Switching JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@19b4748] to manual commit>
2012-02-08 13:23:02,263 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction commit>
2012-02-08 13:23:02,263 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@19b4748]>
2012-02-08 13:23:02,278 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@19b4748] after transaction>
2012-02-08 13:23:02,278 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - <Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource>
2012-02-08 13:23:02,278 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer#0]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT>
2012-02-08 13:23:02,311 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Acquired Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1a41cc7] for JDBC transaction>
```

Below are my spring config

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE" />
    <property name="user" value="migration" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageDelegate" class="com.test.oracle.aq.ProductDelegate" />
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"   
    transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    message-converter="messageConverter" 
    container-class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer" destination-type="topic">
    <jms:listener destination="MIGRATION.PRODUCT_QUEUE" ref="messageDelegate" method="handleMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
<bean id="messageConverter"                                                          
        class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.support.converter.oracle.MappingAdtMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.support.oracle.StructDatumMapper">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="MIGRATION.PRODUCT_T"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="com.test.oracle.aq.Product"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="connectionFactory" data-source="dataSource"/> 
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: In point 4, the transaction manager seems to be the problem child. It is creating too many transactions even when there is no message on the queue. Plus it takes arround 30 sec to commit transaction as per below log <br>
    2012-02-08 13:26:37,731 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - <SQL update affected 1 rows> 2012-02-08 13:26:57,295 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction commit>  <br>
If I remove the transactin manager from listener container, it solves the problem...any idea what is wrong here